# How can I get the total count of total pages of a PDF file using PDFMiner in Python?

Tags: python, pdfminer

In [pypdf](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/), I can get the total number of pages of a PDF file via:

```
from pypdf import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")
no_of_pages = len(reader.pages)
```

How can I get this using [PDFMiner](https://pypi.org/project/pdfminer/)?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I hate to just leave a code snippet. For context here is a [link to the current pdfminer.six repo](https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six/blob/master/pdfminer/pdftypes.py#L77) where you might be able to learn a little more about the `resolve1` method.

As you're working with PDFMiner, you might print and come across some `PDFObjRef` objects. Essentially you can use `resolve1` to expand those objects (they're usually a dictionary).

```
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import resolve1

file = open('some_file.pdf', 'rb')
parser = PDFParser(file)
document = PDFDocument(parser)

# This will give you the count of pages
print(resolve1(document.catalog['Pages'])['Count'])
```

Answer (score 7):

Using [pdfminer.six](https://pypi.org/project/pdfminer.six/) you just need to import the high level function `extract_pages`, convert the generator into a list and take its length.

```py
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_pages

print(len(list(extract_pages(pdf_file))))
```

Comment: while much simpler, this solution performs substantially slower than accepted solution.

Answer (score 4):

I realize you were asking for PDFMiner. However, people coming via Google Search to this question might also be interested in **alternatives to PDFMiner**.

### PyPDF2

[PyPDF2](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/) is a pure-python alternative that recently improved a lot (e.g. text extraction / decryption):

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")
pdf_page_count = len(reader.pages)
```

### Pike

[Docs](https://pikepdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html)

```
from pikepdf import Pdf
pdf_doc = Pdf.open('fourpages.pdf')
pdf_page_count = len(pdf_doc.pages)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `pdfminer`,`import` the necessary modules.

```
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
```

Create a PDF parser object associated with the file object.

```
fp = open('your_file.pdf', 'rb')
parser = PDFParser(fp)
```

Create a PDF document object that stores the document structure.

```
document = PDFDocument(parser)
```

Iterate through the `create_pages()` function incrementing each time there is a page.

```
num_pages = 0
for page in PDFPage.create_pages(document):
    num_pages += 1
print(num_pages)
```

Comment: well I know that.
thats not the point.
if you may see the question you will realise the issue is that "is there any built in function" to tell the number of pages directly before the loop

Comment: Yes, I've seen the question. There's not a built-in function from `pdfminer` that does that. If you knew you had to do a workaround, wouldn't it make sense then that there's no direct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I found PDFMiner very slow in getting the total number of pages. I found this to be a cleaner and faster solution:

`pip3 install PyPDF2`

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader

def get_pdf_page_count(path):
  with open(path, 'rb') as fl:
    reader = PdfFileReader(fl)
    return reader.getNumPages()
```

Comment: PyPDF2 is not maintained anymore. use pdfminer instead

Comment: But the original [pypdf](https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf) is maintained again and can be used instead.